# How can I implement a dynamic class in my view?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic 2, which sits on top of Angular 2.  I would like to have a class added to my `ion-header` element.  This is to allow me to have the header have a transparent background initially, but a solid background on scroll.

I am setting a variable in my Typescript file, and updating that variable when the user scrolls.

I need to set the class based on the variable in my Typescript variable.  I have done this elsewhere in my app with `[ngClass]="{showBack: navBack}"` but this doesn't seem to work on this page.

Typescript:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-class',
  templateUrl: 'class.html'
})
export class ClassPage {
  @ViewChild(Content)
  content: Content;
  navBack: boolean = false;

  constructor(...){}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.content.ionScroll.subscribe((event) => {
      if(event.scrollTop == 0) {
        this.navBack = false;
      } else {
        this.navBack = true;
      }
    });
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-header [ngClass]="{showBack: navBack}">
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Test</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <p style="height: 300px">Long page of content here.</p>
  <p style="height: 300px">Long page of content here.</p>
  <p style="height: 300px">Long page of content here.</p>
</ion-content>
```

I would expect to see a `showBack` CSS class on my `ion-header` which appears on scroll, however it never appears, regardless of the value of `event.scrollTop`.

I have done some debugging with `console.log`s on the `ngAfterViewInit` function, and I can confirm the variable is being changed correctly, but the class does not update.

Comment: Just add quotes to try? What I found in the doc trying to help you : https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-targets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for something to trigger change detection it needs to be executed within Angular’s zone.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-class',
  templateUrl: 'class.html'
})
export class ClassPage {
  @ViewChild(Content)
  content: Content;
  navBack: boolean = false;

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone){}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.content.ionScroll.subscribe((event) => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
          if(event.scrollTop == 0) {
            this.navBack = false;
          } else {
            this.navBack = true;
          }
    });
   });
}

}
```

Comment: That's fixed it.  Can you explain what the issue here was?  It's a bit confusing, because `this.navBack` was updating, just not updating the view, so what is `ngZone` doing?

Comment: Somehow `ionScroll` code leaves Angulars zone and breaks change detection. So we are triggering change detection manually using `ngZone`.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be:

```
[ngClass]="{'showBack': navBack}"
```

(you're missing single quotes)

Comment: Quite possibly - I've tried it, but the class still does not appear.  Likewise, if I default the value to `true` in my Typescript it always shows and is not updated by the `ionScroll.subscribe` event (which is definitely being called).

Comment: Wierd, why not try [class.showBack]="navBack" - which is often used when working with a single class

Comment: Nope - same with that too.  I have put it on a `div` as well, just in case `ion-header` had some odd functionality on it preventing class manipulation, but it's the same deal there.  It seems that changes made in the Typescript aren't updating the variable in the view.